# Unable to access login page or my website

Tags: control-panel

I have been unable to access my website or log into my CMS. I have checked with the server and everything is OK there but all I am getting is a blank page.

I updated craft manually following the instructions given.

I also have a staging site which I use for sharing with my client and this all works fine.

Is there anything I need to be checking? What will have stopped the website from working? I would really appreciate any help you can give with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your question I'm assuming that the site worked before an update, then it stopped working after the update. I'd either download the update manually, replace the app folder and set permissions, or submit a ticket to P&T including error logs.

Comment: Can you check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files and search them for any [error] or [warning] log entries that might be related to failed login attempts?

Comment: As far as I know the site was working fine before the update @codeknight. I also updated craft manually. I will check with the logs as suggested Brad and see whats what. Cheers for your help.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved, @PatrickWilbourne?

Comment: @PatrickWilbourne, are you still out there?

Answer (score 3):

One small detail that can cause the front-end and back-end of your site to result in a blank white page, is if you have a syntax error in your `general.php` file, such as a missing comma at the end of a line.  If you've just made a recent edit to your config files, take a closer look at them and make sure that you don't have any small errors.

For example, the following multi-environment config is missing a comma at the end of the `omitScriptNameInUrls` setting, and that minor detail would make both the front-end and back-end of a site result in a blank white page:

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true
        'devMode' => false
    )
);
```